# Sorting a list of UUID v1 in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, uuid

What is the best and FASTEST way to sort a UUID v1 list:

```
ss = [(uuid1(), i, time.sleep(i)) for i in range(10)]

ss
[(UUID('9a5e8b20-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 0, None), (UUID('9a5e9246-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 1, None), (UUID('9af75166-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 2, None), (UUID('9c28d4ba-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 3, None), (UUID('9df31a58-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 4, None), (UUID('a056198a-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 5, None), (UUID('a351c986-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 6, None), (UUID('a6e63dc0-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 7, None), (UUID('4f418380-cfac-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 8, None), (UUID('7de51c1e-d075-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 9, None)]
```

It is not always giving correct results using the following statement:

```
sorted(ss, key= lambda x: x[0])

[(UUID('4f418380-cfac-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 8, None), (UUID('7de51c1e-d075-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 9, None), (UUID('9a5e8b20-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 0, None), (UUID('9a5e9246-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 1, None), (UUID('9af75166-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 2, None), (UUID('9c28d4ba-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 3, None), (UUID('9df31a58-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 4, None), (UUID('a056198a-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 5, None), (UUID('a351c986-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 6, None), (UUID('a6e63dc0-be62-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf'), 7, None)]
```

The Expected order is: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and not 8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Note that the list I want to sort has only UUIDs: sorting by x[1] in the above example won't work for me.

Comment: Try `sorted(ss, key= lambda x: x[1])` `x[0]` is the first item (UUID)

Comment: My actual list does not have x[1] but only UUID's  .I am using the x[1] only in the example to check whether the oder we get is correct

Comment: Why do you expect that order?  `7de51c1e-d075-11e3-87fa-0800270bf8cf` is the last UUID in your example, with `i=9`.  Why shouldn't it be second in the sorted list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's UUIDs are sorted according to the `int` property which is the only member of a UUID object.

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, UUID):
        return cmp(self.int, other.int)
    return NotImplemented
```

This is different from the "timestamp" part of the UUID v1 object (which you can access as the `time` property) because they refer to the underlying byte sequnce with different orders:

```
>>> x = uuid.uuid1()
>>> x
UUID('488085a8-be83-11e3-a999-1803733f0b7d')
>>> x.int
96371740624175594482388131032705469309L
>>> ((((((((((x.time_low << 16) | x.time_mid) << 16) | x.time_hi_version) << 8) | x.clock_seq_hi_variant) << 8) | x.clock_seq_low) << 48) | x.node) == x.int
True
>>> x.time
136161884817622440L
>>> (((((x.time_hi_version & 0xFFF) << 16) | x.time_mid) << 32) | x.time_low) == x.time
True
```

So you need to specify the "time" property when you sort UUID v1 objects according to thier timestamps:

```
sorted(ss, key= lambda x: x[0].time)
```

Comment: Is that second chunk supposed to be in code blocks, or is the block quotes deliberate?